# Find out which client IP and Query using highest network Bandwidth from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to know which clients (IP or Hostname) are taking highest bandwidth from server and by what query they are taking high bandwidth.

Field Names:

```
Client Name/IP, Query, KB transferred, Date&Time of query executed, Time took to execute
```

Is there anyway to get it done in SQL Server?

Thanks Sanket

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about what passes through your network card. Feels more like a question for a network guy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about networking

Comment: AFAIK - SQL Server doesn't keep track of packets/KB sent. Let me further specify: sys.dm_exec_connections will have most of it, but a connection can have multiple sessions, not to mention if connection pooling would be used. so while it *does* keep track of it, it might not be at the level you would like.

Answer (score 2):

The DMVs sys.dm_exec_connections and sys.dm_exec_sql_text have most of what you need.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 session_id, connect_time, num_reads, num_writes, last_read, last_write, client_net_address, most_recent_sql_handle, x.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( most_recent_sql_handle ) x
ORDER BY num_reads + num_writes DESC
```

You might also wish to review some of the other DMVs, eg sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_exec_sessions for useful information.